# ASP.NET Core async request handler always responds with 200 OK and empty body if it's a separate method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using the ASP.NET Core 6 minimal APIs to build an API. After extracting anonymous/lambda handlers from `MapGet` into their own methods, some endpoints act erroneously by always returning a 200 (OK) response with an empty body.

Not sure whether I've missed some gotcha regarding how `async` works in C# or whether this is a bug with ASP.NET Core.

### Reproducible example

Following is a minimal example where endpoints `/a` and `/b` execute similar methods, but one of them never responds as expected. To run the example, just copy the code into a new project created with `dotnet new web`.

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

async Task<int> longRunningValueGenerator() {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return 4; // chosen by a fair dice roll
              // guaranteed to be random
}

async Task<IResult> getValueA(HttpContext http) {
    if(http.Request.Query["secret"] != "test") {
        return Results.Unauthorized();
    }

    var value = await longRunningValueGenerator();
    return Results.Ok(new {
        Value = value
    });
}

app.MapGet("/", () => "get /a or /b with secret=test");
app.MapGet("/a", getValueA);
app.MapGet("/b", async (HttpContext http) => {
    if(http.Request.Query["secret"] != "test") {
        return Results.Unauthorized();
    }

    var value = await longRunningValueGenerator();
    return Results.Ok(new {
        Value = value
    });
});
app.Run();
```

### Some observations

- This issue starts occurring once the *secret* check is added. This is just for example, adding different code also triggers this behavior.
- It still takes a second (as determined by the delay) for the server to respond if *secret* is correct, even for `getValueA`.
- `/a` will never respond with a different status code other than 200, even if *secret* is incorrect.
- Non-async handlers that are separate methods work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple of overloads for `MapGet`:

- [`MapGet(IEndpointRouteBuilder, String, Delegate)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.endpointroutebuilderextensions.mapget?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-builder-endpointroutebuilderextensions-mapget(microsoft-aspnetcore-routing-iendpointroutebuilder-system-string-system-delegate))
- [`MapGet(IEndpointRouteBuilder, String, RequestDelegate)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.endpointroutebuilderextensions.mapget?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-builder-endpointroutebuilderextensions-mapget(microsoft-aspnetcore-routing-iendpointroutebuilder-system-string-microsoft-aspnetcore-http-requestdelegate))

The difference between these two signatures is in that last parameter, `Delegate` vs `RequestDelegate`. `Delegate` represents any callable function, but `RequestDelegate` represents a function with one parameter, `HttpContext`, that returns a `Task`.

In your example, the `getValueA` function works for both of these delegates: it's any callable function and it's a function that takes `HttpContext`. For reasons beyond my understanding, the compiler picks the `RequestDelegate` version of `MapGet`, and effectively throws away the `IResult` value that it isn't expecting.

There might be a few options for fixing this, but the following solution should work well here. It changes your `getValueA` signature and takes advantage of parameter-binding for `secret`:

```
async Task<IResult> getValueA([FromQuery] string secret)
{
    if (secret != "test")
    {
        return Results.Unauthorized();
    }

    var value = await longRunningValueGenerator();
    return Results.Ok(new
    {
        Value = value
    });
}
```

This change means that the version of `MapGet` that takes a `RequestDelegate` is no longer a candidate, and therefore the `Delegate` version is called and processed correctly.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with .NET 6 and minimal APIs and it has to do with overload resolution and what gets inferred by default https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39956.

It has been fixed in .NET 7, we may backport to .NET 6 (you can request a back port on the issue).

Answer (score 1):

Kirk Larkin's answer helped me a lot. I was spending several hours. But when knowing that the compiler chooses the overload with the `RequestDelegate` parameter it makes perfectly sense! Thanks!

There is a way to "force" the compiler to use the overload with `Delegate` parameter. Simply add the formal parameter name separated with a colon ":" in front of the actual parameter, like so:

```
app.MapGet("/a", handler: getValueA);
```

Because the formal parameter's name of the `Delegate` overload is `handler`, the compiler now takes the correct overload.